# How to start game with new character without shared stash?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3 I have a hero with lots of gold, items and whatnot. How do I start fresh with the other hero?

When I created a new character (on the same battle.net account) I had access to the stash and gold of the older hero.

Is it even possible to *unlink* that connection?

Comment: someone  here https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/19974497268 suggested a that you can request a hard reset with a token http://us.battle.net/en/ . Unsure if that helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called Season. Those run for a few months and are then "reset". Each Season you start completely from scratch. New character, no stash, no gold, etc.

Outside Season, the only option I can think of is to switch from softcore to hardcore. Characters in Hardcore will share a stash and gold, but it will not be shared between softcore/hardcore.

So to summarize:

- Each season offers a start from scratch (though only once per season again)
- Switching to hardcore offers a start from scratch (only once for a lifetime)
- A season offers a fresh start for softcore as well as hardcore -> 2 fresh starts per season

The next season (season 16) starts on the 18th January 2019

Comment: You can also rebirth an existing character for use in the season, and they'll start again from level 1, with no gear, gold, story progress or merchant upgrades.

Comment: Anyone knows what happens if all hardcore characters die? Does that reset stash etc as well?

Comment: That would make a good question for the site. You should post it.

Comment: Accoring to [this FAQ](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/5235397272)(at least what google preview shows), stash etc will be kept even if all hardcore characters die. So its possible to start from scratch two times per season and one time (switch to hardcore) in normal mode

Comment: Seasons are the best answer, but if it's a once off thing, then you can simply change your region. The characters in the European region are completely separate to US region and nothing can ever be shared between them. You can toggle this option form the launcher before starting the game. Note that this change may increase you ping ever so slightly.